# form's Label Style modification in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, label, haml

I am very fresher in ROR and in my application I want Form's Label initial started with capital. I am aware that by default it takes first word's initial as capital but not aware how to give second word's initial as Capital. Let me clear you with example...

I tried this code for Label :

```
= f.label :campaign_Title
```

Giving Output:

```
Campaign title
```

Expected Output:

```
Campaign Title  #title's initial should be capital 'T'
```

if I used `%label` without form object it works but I don't want that..

Here's another Question..

If I want first initial small then? like..

`name` instead of `Name`.. 
I know it doesn't make any difference but would like to know if there any trick..
Thanks in Advance.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<%= f.label :campaign_Title, "Campaign Title" %>
```

You can pass any custom value as the second parameter of label helper

Answer (score 0):

You can use a block to style and customise the label contents;

```
<%= f.label :campaign_title do %>
  Campaign Title
<% end %>
```